# ASP.NET Core MVC : load file inside Razor page

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make the terms and conditions page form my site. However, I am trying to provide the terms and conds page in the language the user prefers like Microsoft (they have this en-US prefix in their URL).

I managed to create separate HTML folders in my `wwwroot` like `terms.en-US.html` and `terms.fr-CA` etc.

I also created a controller named `FilesController` and it looks like this:

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    [Route("Files/{language}/Terms")]
    public IActionResult Terms(string language)
    {
        ViewData["lang"] = language;
        return View();
    }
}
```

And this is the `Terms.cshtml` file (so far):

```
@{
   Layout= "_HomeLayout";
}
@Html.Raw(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"../files/documents/terms_and_conditions/" + @ViewData["lang"] + ".html")));
```

But obviously it doesnt work. How can I manage this?

PS: the only reason I am trying to add *html* into *cshtml* file is to benefit from the *layout* feature. Otherwise I would have directly return the html file in the controller like this:

```
public IActionResult Terms()
{
    return File("~/files/documents/terms_and_conditions/tr-TR.html", "text/html");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use `File.ReadAllText` to read the path directly and it works fine.

Below is my test code:

View:

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText("./wwwroot/files/"+@ViewData["lang"]+".html"))
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string language)
{
      ViewData["lang"] = language;
      return View();
}
```

[image]

Test Result:

[image]

Is this result what you want?